# Ansible Playbook for Unix checking ACL and updating the id and group details of the folder

Tags: ansible

I need Help on Ansible playbook.

I have few unix servers. I want to check the ACL permissions of any particular folder, apart from the id and group if any other user or group available in acl it should says you have acl and exist. If no acl then it should update the permissions to the folder to 750.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow ,  it's recommended to do a research and test some code before asking here. These modules could be helpful  [acl module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/acl_module.html) &  [stat module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html)

Comment: This don't help.

Comment: Did the answer help?

Comment: How to mark as right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[acl_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/acl_module.html) can be used to obtain the acl for files and folders.
On files without acl the output is:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "user::rw-",
        "group::r--",
        "other::r--"
    ]
}
```

On files with acl:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "user::rwx",
        "user:gluster:rw-",
        "user:ubuntu:rw-",
        "group::r-x",
        "group:gluster:rw-",
        "mask::rwx",
        "other::r-x"
    ]
}
```

When there is an acl defined, the output would include either `user:` or `group:` or both of them.
My solution is to search for those values in the output (excluding `user::` and `group::` using regex `user:([^:])` which means: no `colon` after `user:`).
 Then set permissions to the directory that doesn't have them:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    target_folder: testdir
  tasks:
  - name: Obtain the ACL for {{ target_folder }}
    ansible.posix.acl:
      path: "{{ target_folder }}"
    register: acl_info

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ acl_info.acl }}"

  - name: Change permissions for file with no acl
    ansible.builtin.file:
      path: "{{ target_folder }}"
      mode: '750'
    when: acl_info.acl is not search("user:([^:])") or acl_info is not search("group:([^:])")
```

Comment: Can you help on this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73575797/ansible-permission-777